# DNS with VLAN issue

Tags: domain-name-system, vlan

I just inherited a network with 2 Linux servers running Debian as a host OS, with VMWare hosting a number of VMs on both, including the domain controllers and some web sites.

Here is the issue, each server has a VM domain controller, AD and DNS are replicated across both controllers. DHCP on the first controller issues IP addresses for the entire LAN, 192. DHCP on the second controller issues IP addresses, 10.10 to a VLAN.

DNS forwarding on the controller correctly forwards internal requests to a web server hosted on a VM on the second Linux server.

Linux1 Hosts Controller2
Linxu2 Hosts Controller1 and VM web site.

Controller2 has correct DNS
Controller1 has replicated DNS

VLAN 10.10 needs to resolve to a VM web site.

DNS lists both domain controllers 1 and 2.

The Forward Lookup Zones are identical except that the Name Servers are switched pointing to the opposite controller.domain

The Host A record points to the same VM

I had tried a Reverse Lookup Zone entry but may have entered it incorrectly.
I also tried public DNS on the client but that returns RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

At one point these changes allowed me to ping the public interface and tracert to same, but it would still not resolve to the web site.

Could someone help with what I think is a fairly simple oversight that I have missed?

controller1 - server1
[image: controller1]

controller2 - server2
[image: controller2]

Comment: Please post the results of `ipconfig /all` for both of your domain controllers. Does DNS forwarding work on one VLAN but not the other?  Or is there some other reason that you mention the VLANs?

Comment: The VLAN I have been told was intended to divert traffic from the 192 LAN. Ipconfigs coming.

Comment: simple question, but does the dns service is bind to the two address ?

Comment: Do you have any DNS forwarders listed on the DNS Manager properties pane? Usually it should have the IP address of your firewall or some other forwarder.

Comment: I am guessing that you are not talking about Conditional Forwarders, in the server properties pane in the Forwarders tab, their are two IPs one is 8.8.8.8 google, the other is a VOIP vendor. They are the same on both controllers

Comment: From the domain controller,  what is the output from `nslookup microsoft.com 8.8.8.8`? What about `tracert google.com`

Comment: On the server? Everything works fine. From a client connected to 10 accessing googles page is not a problem, everything on the public internet works fine. Its just getting back to the internal VM web site.